# Is there any function in python that can errase specific columns if the value is NaN but maint the rest of the data in the dataframe

Tags: python, finance, stock

I have a problem, my data is of the nasdaq daily prices and i want to errase the stocks that dont have recent prices, but that it doesnt errase the data that is right. PLEASE HELP

Im trying with these codes
nasdaq=np.array(nasdaq.to_records())
print(nasdaq)
print(type(nasdaq))

Comment: `nasdaq.dropna(how='any', inplace=True)`  think you need:

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your question correctly, but if you change the data to panda Dataframe format, you can drop columns with NaN values like this

```
df = df.dropna(axis='columns')
```